# Me aparece el error StringIndexOutOfBoundsException en java

Tags: java

EL error que tengo es al poner 5 o mas palabras en la consola, pero con hasta 4 funciona perfectamente. Me seria de ayuda que me pudiese ayudar alguien con esto, no tengo ni idea de porque pasa esto.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1 = sc.nextLine();
    String[] partes1 = str1.split(" ");
    int si = 0;
    int no = 0;

    if (partes1.length >= 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < partes1.length - 1; i++) {
            if ((partes1[i].charAt(partes1.length - 1) == partes1[i + 1].charAt(1)) && (partes1[i].charAt(partes1.length - 2) == partes1[i + 1].charAt(0))) {
                si++;
            } else if ((partes1[i].charAt(partes1.length - 1) != partes1[i + 1].charAt(1)) || (partes1[i].charAt(partes1.length - 2) != partes1[i + 1].charAt(0))) {
                no++;
            }
            System.out.println(partes1[i]);
        }
        if (no > 0) {
            System.out.println("NO");
        } else {
            System.out.println("SI");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("SI");
    }
```

Comment: ¿Que necesitas realizar en el ejercicio? Para entender un poco el por que del código.

Comment: Entiendo que mete una serie de palabras por consola y tiene que comprobar  que las 2 últimas letras de una palabra son las mismas que las dos primeras de la siguiente palabra.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error está en las comprobaciones al poner partes1.length, aquí la solución:

```
if ((partes1[i].charAt(partes1[i].length()- 1) == partes1[i + 1].charAt(1)) && (partes1[i].charAt(partes1[i].length() - 2) == partes1[i + 1].charAt(0))) {
    si++;
} else if ((partes1[i].charAt(partes1[i].length() - 1) != partes1[i + 1].charAt(1)) || (partes1[i].charAt(partes1.length - 2) != partes1[i + 1].charAt(0))) {
    no++;
}
```

De todas formas el programa dará error si alguna de las palabras tienen menos de 2 letras de longitud.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que querías es que las dos últimas letras de una palabra fueran las mismas que las dos primeras de la siguiente como dijo @alexval entonces esta es la solución

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1 = sc.nextLine();
        String[] partes1 = str1.split(" ");
        int si = 0;
        int no = 0;

        if (partes1.length >= 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < partes1.length; i++) {
                if (i + 1 < partes1.length) {
                    if ((partes1[i].charAt(partes1[i].length() - 1) == partes1[i + 1].charAt(1)) && (partes1[i].charAt(partes1[i].length() - 2) == partes1[i + 1].charAt(0))) {
                        si++;
                    } else if ((partes1[i].charAt(partes1[i].length() - 1) != partes1[i + 1].charAt(1)) || (partes1[i].charAt(partes1[i].length() - 2) != partes1[i + 1].charAt(0))) {
                        no++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(partes1[i]);
            }
            if (no > 0) {
                System.out.println("NO");
            } else {
                System.out.println("SI");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("SI");
        }
```

Lo que pasaba es que estabas obteniendo el carácter con la función `charAt()` en la posición del tamaño del arreglo `partes1.length` y lo que requerías era con el tamaño de la longitud de la palabra `partes1[i].length()`.

Comment: el "if (i + 1 < partes1.length)" sobra si en el for pones "partes1.length-1" como ha puesto él

Comment: Gracias por apoyar pero considera leer [answer], los aportes que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, una explicación que identifique lo que hiciste ayudaría mucho

Comment: @alexval Si es cierto! Lo hice así porque no imprimía la última palabra pero hubiera bastado con una impresión final.